# How best to save to the database

Tags: java, mysql, sql, database, mariadb

everyone,

I have a database of companies with a unique ID (Auto Increment), the name of the company and the owner.

So now here's how can I best store employees in the database where the employees can be in multiple companies? So that the queries are not so complicated?

I hope you understand what I mean

Comment: Can you provide more details. how you have implemented your database and how complex are your queries now?

Comment: The database for the companies is already described above. The employee database is not yet created because I do not know how to do it best and therefore there are no queries yet.

Comment: Employee (employee_id), company (company_id), company_employee(company_id,employee_id)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your problem you need 3 tables, by convention table's names are singular :

```
Table company (
 id int unsigned auto_increment,
 name varchar(255)
)

Table employee (
 id int unsigned auto_increment,
 name varchar(255)
)
```

and a 3rd table that links them

```
Table employee_company (
 employee_id int unsigned,
 company_id int unsigned
)
```

If you want all the employees of a company x :

```
SELECT c.name AS company_name, e.name AS employee_name
    FROM company c, employee e, employee_company ec
    WHERE c.name = x
    AND c.id = ec.company_id
    AND e.id = ec.employee_id
    ORDER BY e.name
```

If you want all the companies for an employee y :

```
    SELECT c.name AS company_name, e.name AS employee_name
    FROM company c, employee e, employee_company ec
    WHERE e.employee_name = y
    AND c.id = ec.company_id
    AND e.id = ec.employee_id
    ORDER BY c.name
```

If you want to know if an employee is in a company :

```
    SELECT ec.employee_id 
    FROM company c, employee e, employee_company ec
    WHERE e.employee_name = employee_name
    AND c.company_name = company_name
    AND c.id = ec.company_id
    AND e.id = ec.employee_id
```

If not found returns false else returns the employee's id

Instead of

```
WHERE e.employee_name = employee_name
```

You could use

```
WHERE e.employee_name like '%employee_name%'
```

Comment: Yeah, that looks really good! Top Thanks. One more question do you have an idea how to make another SQL query so I can check if this employee is an employee of the company? so I can build a function that returns true/false?

Comment: better said I need a query if the employee is an employee of company x?